# Is the (truncated) Witt ring an injective module over itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules, injective-module

Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p$. I read that $W_n(k)$ is injective as a $W_n(k)$-module. I did not find a direct reference for this, but I assume it has to do with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232291/r-ra-is-an-injective-module-over-itself).

My question is, is this still the case for the infinite Witt vectors $W(k)$? If not in general, are there conditions under which this might be true?

Comment: @KReiser would you mind giving a reference? As far as I know, $W(k)$ is a DVR, no? See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ring+of+Witt+vectors. In particular the $p$-adic integers are not a field.

Comment: @KReiser A DVR is an integral domain. According to Wikipedia, "no integral domain that is not a field is self-injective".

Comment: Ugh, I misremembered and was careless. Yeah, you're correct, you always get the ring of integers of some extension of $\Bbb Z_p$, so it's always a DVR and thus _never_ injective over itself. Yeesh.